# Função com vetores em C

Tags: c

Gostaria de saber como seria uma função em C que recebesse um vetor com N elementos e retornasse a quantidade de elementos que estão acima da média aritmética do próprio vetor.

Comment: Bem-vindo ao StackOverflow em Português! Você poderia mostrar o código que você já fez? Você também pode ver [como fazer uma pergunta na Central de Ajuda Como Perguntar](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 2):

Segue um exemplo (testado) de como calcular a `quantidade de elementos` contidos em um vetor que estão `acima da média aritmética` desse mesmo vetor.

Para uma maior legibilidade, clareza e modularidade do código, dividi a tarefa em duas funções: uma delas `double media( double vetor[], int tam )` calcula a média aritmética dos elementos em um vetor, enquanto a outra `int media_qtd_acima( double vetor[], int tam )` faz a contagem de quantos elementos estão acima da média:

```
#include <stdio.h>

double media( double vetor[], int tam )
{
    int i = 0;
    double soma = 0.0;

    for( i = 0; i < tam; i++ )
        soma += vetor[ i ];

    return soma / tam;
}

int media_qtd_acima( double vetor[], int tam )
{
    int i = 0;
    int n = 0;
    double med = media( vetor, tam );

    for( i = 0; i < tam; i++ )
        if( vetor[i] > med )
            n++;

    return n;
}

int main( void )
{
    double v[ 10 ] = { 5.03, 5.7, 2.89, 1.97, 1.04, 3.3, 7.8, 9.12, 0.08, 8.41 };

    printf( "Media: %g\n", media( v, 10 ) );
    printf( "Qtd. de amostras acima da media: %d\n", media_qtd_acima( v, 10 ) );

    return 0;
}
```

Saída:

```
./media 
Media: 4.534
Qtd. de amostras acima da media: 5
```

Comment: Valeu cara! Funcionou!